# Calling Simple Procedure in PHP which Outputs Variable

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I am Trying to call a Simple Procedure which returns name to PHP Page.

I am Getting empty record set while doing this

**Procedure**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prSample1;
CREATE PROCEDURE prSample1(OUT Name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
 SET Name = 'Mugil';
 SELECT Name;
END;
```

**PHP Procedure Call**

```
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('dbName');

    $strSQL = "CALL prSample1(@Name);";
    $Result = mysql_query($strSQL);

    $strSQL = "SELECT @Name";
    $Result = mysql_query($strSQL);

    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
      $Name = $Row[0];

    print $Name;
```

I am not getting the Name when i run This PHP Code.

Thank you fro your reply

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: (i) use `mysqli` as mysql is now unsupported. (ii) Since the call doesn't return a result set, why not just simply `... mysqli_query( "CALL prSample1(@Name);SELECT @Name") ...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Thanks alot for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

```
$strSQL = "CALL prSample1(@Name);";
```

should be:

```
$strSQL = "CALL prSample1(@Name)";
```

Mind the ";" :)